# What does cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true) do?

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I haven't found clear documentation or explanation on this one. I guess it prefixes cache keys with the cache name but I am not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if true, redis key use *zset* to store, false is *string*